# INSERT ON DUPLICATE updates unrelated row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I currently have a table with 3 columns, ID (primary ai), Key (unique binary(32)), Value (string) and that's it. Key is just the sha256 binary value of Value.

I'm testing my database by doing a lot of prepared batch inserts statements, each with 1-200 values at random. The reason I'm updating Value is incase Value somehow got changed overtime, I always want Value to match the Key hash

```
INSERT INTO kv (key, value) VALUES (UNHEX(?), ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id, value = VALUES(value)
```

My problem is after inserting a bunch of random data when I look in my database some of my values are getting overwritten and I'm not sure why. A Key of sha256("100") could randomly have a Value of "123". Only a small amount of my data is incorrect, but the fact any of it is incorrect is bothersome.

I've turned on mysqld logging for all sql statements and all of my insert statements show Key: sha256("100") Value: "100" being inserted, never would "123" or any incorrect data appear in logs, but in the database it would be the incorrect value.

My problem is my data doesn't match my statements?

I've tried emptying my database and rerunning all of the statements individually one by one slowly and all of my data stays correct.

I'm not sure what or how I should go about looking for what the problem might be, I tried MariaDB 10.0.26 and 10.1.14 and both times I've run into this issue.

(added from comment:)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip_raw (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    tokenhash binary(32) NOT NULL, 
    tokenvalue varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY token (tokenhash)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: I am slightly confused. While there are occasional issues with these updates (a row with an auto increment primary key of 0 seems to cause issues), you appear to be updating the value but not the encoded value. Hence if value ever changes the encoded value in the key field will not be changed.

Comment: I want the Key to always remain the same forever tied to its ID since it's unique. If the Value were ever to be unintentionally changed I would want the Value to be updated at a later point if it can ever be recovered. id=id just insures a noop on a unique key insert if it already exists, I added value = VALUES(value) as extra in case the value of value unintentionally changed

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table? There are notes on not using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE when there are multiple unique indexes, but not sure how this could cause the issue you have. Can you export some details (table declares. basic data and the updated statements) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: no triggers, this is my only db scheme

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip_raw (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tokenhash binary(32) NOT NULL,
  tokenvalue varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY token (tokenhash)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;`

Comment: my batch inserts of random size look like so:

`INSERT INTO ip_raw (tokenhash, tokenvalue) VALUES (UNHEX('b8d4d60e7f9c0bf2ae6b4c67512d347e1638c8978d1e3e1ed85890e11417ccbe'), '9013'), (UNHEX('3b38239024a8c579f48e9cc3b3c5bf5aeaa06b841877488b90ffa07e2e73180c'), '7120'), (UNHEX('2ee62f16ca41fe7879853975d5fcb4cb858f6edb5fd0355cfb7948d997e6b6a9'), '3312'), (UNHEX('a367613375c7fcd7402955ec5143e208948604a13765c1805450f350ba570d3d'), '1152') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id, tokenvalue = VALUES(tokenvalue)`

I'm trying to find information on not using multiple unique indexes but can't find anything

Comment: Why are you updating the id (ie you have _UPDATE id=id_ )? Id is the auto increment primary key.

Comment: it's a no-op, I can remove it but the same thing will happen

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - _In addition, an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement against a table having more than one unique or primary key is also marked as unsafe._ . But I doubt that is causing the issue you are having. I cannot see a reason for it to corrupt the _tokenvalue_ field. I cannot replicate it with the details you have given.

Comment: Do you check for errors after each statement?

Comment: If you don't need `id` anywhere else, get rid of it and promote the `UNIQUE` key to `PRIMARY KEY`.  This will save space, speed up things, etc.